# Putting Images on the top right

Tags: graphics

Hi everyone am just a beginner on latex, can anyone please show me, how to put a picture on the top right or top left and on bottom left and bottom right only thanks.

Comment: You could use package `textpos` or do it with `tikz` (see Absolute Positioning in the manual).

Comment: Top/bottom right/left of what?

Comment: I would like to display a picture on the top right corner of a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility ist using `tikz` with the `current page` node.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{mwe}% example pictures

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east)
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to run twice.

[image]